# Very Weird Shape On The Graph Of Percision/Recall

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am doing classification on the classic Titanic dataset， and I have encountered this weird looking graph of Precision and recall.

I used SGD model as the classifier. Two lines are overlapped and looking like nonsense. Can some experienced programmer tell me what kind of problem do I have, this definitely does not look correct. Thanks.

`y_scores=cross_val_predict(sgd_clf,X,y,cv=5,method='decision_function')`

`from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve`
`precisions,recalls,thresholds=precision_recall_curve(y,y_scores)`

`def plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold(precisions,recall,threshold):`

```
plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold
plt.plot(thresholds,precisions[:-1],'b--',label='Precision')
plt.plot(thresholds,precisions[:-1],'g-',label='Recall')
plt.xlabel('Threshold')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.ylim([0,1])
```

`plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold(precisions,recalls,thresholds)`
`plt.savefig('plot_precision_recall_vs_threshold2.png')`
`plt.show()`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following two lines you only changed the label but not the array that is plotted `precisions[:-1]`, which might explain why the lines overlap.

```py
plt.plot(thresholds,precisions[:-1],'b--',label='Precision')
plt.plot(thresholds,precisions[:-1],'g-',label='Recall')
```

try replacing the second one with `recalls[:,-1]`

Comment: yeah its solved, what a stupid mistake have I made. :(

Comment: We've all been there. Happy to help :)

Comment: Are most untuned models have a graph look like this or is it just because my model is specially awful? Can you please make an interpretation on possible problems? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sadly I'm not familiar enough with the function to completely understand what is going on there. I also couldn't find an example where precision and recall were plotted over the threshold, only [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py)